# How to do a temporary acoustic treatment of a living room with kitchen extensions, windows and irregular shapes?

Tags: acoustics, isolation, room-treatment

Hi all sound design wizards, hope you are keeping safe wherever you are!

I am music producer outside my other regular job, and I make instrumentals, record vocals mix and master in my living room. My living room has this irregular shape (images below) and has an extension kitchen and windows. I am looking into suggestions on how to do some minimal but decently effective acoustic treatment (not isolation),to improve my experience with the stuff I mention above. Importantly, I will be living here potentially for two more years only, so ideally I want a temporary solution that can be reused elsewhere whenever I move, and I also can't damage the current place in any way.

Here is what my room looks like:
On the window side, where I currently have my gear:
[image]

on the side that is next to the kitchen
[image]

the roof is slightly tilted (Triangular shape) and has some spacings created with wood.
[image]

and here is my very poor approximate schematic of how the room is overall
[image]

My biggest difficulty from my research so far is how to deal with the window, I can't block it as it has to be able to open, but on the other side there is the kitchen, which I assume the lack of a contiguous wall on the kitchen side in one side would create unwanted noise

are acoustic foams, bass traps in specific places  worth it?

Any suggestions are very much appreciated

Comment: Quick test before anything else. See how much mileage you can gain by simply taking your existing working position & drag the whole desk, speakers & all,  into that corner at 45°, across where the mic & lamp are in the 1st pic.

Comment: thanks @Tetsujin, will try that

Comment: Adding some "heavy" (this is indeed quite vague) curtains on the windows could possible provide some decent results on the high and possibly mid-high frequencies. Maybe if you could provide some measurements of your room (spatial and/or frequency responses) could help people providing some advice without having to guess what the problem(s) may be in your room.